# Meaning of "snowy detail"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In an app's description, I found the following sentence:

> The game has a frozen wasteland that is full of beautiful scenes. You
>   will want to replay it many times to ensure that you don't miss a single
>   snowy detail.

The M-W dictionary mentions the following meanings of the word "detail":

> 1 : extended treatment of or attention to particular items
>
> 2 : a part of a whole a : a small and subordinate part : PARTICULAR
>   also : a reproduction of such a part of a work of art
>
> b : a part considered or requiring to be considered separately from
>   the whole
>
> c : the small elements that collectively constitute a work of art
>
> d photography : the small elements of an image corresponding to those
>   of the subject
>
> 3a : selection of a person or group for a particular task (as in
>   military service)
>
> b(1) : the person or group selected
>
> (2) : the task to be performed

However, I do not find any of the above-mentioned meanings relevant to the phrase "snowy detail".

Comment: In this context, snowy detail = details related to the snow scene.

Comment: Yep, it can be interpreted quite literally.

Comment: (2.c. is probably the best definition of "detail" for this case.)

Comment: Details in pictures are details in  pictures. Scenes can be of snow, of water, of land or anything at all. And all those scenes have adjectives.

Answer (score 1):

Definition 2c is particularly appropriate in this case.  The article is recommending that you replay the app so you have more chances to see all of the details.

Snowy here is just an adjective being used to describe the details.